Generated Typescript Files From Proto Files Have Can't resolve Error
After generating file of typescript from proto, I am facing Can't resolve Error in my ReactJs with TypeScript Project. Everything looks perfect. Have a look to screenshot

My Error Screenshot Is:

Facing Error at this line even it looks all okay to me

I am using this command for generating files

...
# Run protoc for RPC
protoc -I=$ROOT_PATH/src/$SERVICE_NAME -I=$IMPORT_PATH $ROOT_PATH/src/$SERVICE_NAME/Protos/*.proto \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=$PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-web=$PROTOC_GEN_GRPC_WEB_PATH \
    --grpc-web_out=import_style=$IMPORT_STYLE,mode=grpcwebtext:$OUT_DIR
...

This error waste my a lot of time

I after spending so much time, I found that somehow, it was not accepting the path as it was generated especially for *.d.ts files.
However it works for me that I change imports for *.d.ts files like this:
I replace my code line from
import * as Protos_raw_item_rpc_pb from '../Protos/raw_item_rpc_pb'; // proto import: "Protos/raw_item_rpc.proto"

To This line
import * as Protos_raw_item_rpc_pb from '../Protos/raw_item_rpc_pb.d'; // proto import: "Protos/raw_item_rpc.proto"


